# making a clickable div over class jquery

Tags: jquery, html, class, events, button

```
<div class="button">asdf</div>


$('.button').click(function(){
    alert("asdf");
}
```

can anybody explain me why this did not work?

its also on http://jsfiddle.net/huLn21t7/5/

Comment: Because you have a syntax error. Have a look at the console.

Comment: Count the number of parentheses, and you'll see you're missing one at the end

Comment: your syntax is wrong

Comment: `);` that is what you are missing after function close brace

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing parenthesis on your javascript.

Try this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    alert("asdf");
});
```